# Google Analytics for embeddable JS modules

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We provide our clients, who are eCommerce website owners, with a JS module that they can embed in their website. It's basically a `<script src=...>` they put in their HTML that loads our JavaScript and shows our UI upon checkout, similar to [this](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial#embedding).

We want to use Google Analytics, but when I go to set it up, it gives me two options:

1. Website - which requires a website URL (which I don't really have because I'm not the website owner, but just an external module to it).
2. Mobile app - which our module isn't really, but rather a web application.

I'm tending towards website property, and have the website URL as the client's. But then will I be able to aggregate all data from all of my clients?

Which one of the options suits my needs best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to select "Web" (and obviously you'd have to get permission from your clients and make sure that you do not interfere with their own tracking etc.).

The difference between the two options is a) that they have slightly different dimensions and metrics (e.g. pageviews vs. screensviews) and b) that they are implemented via different means (analytics.js library vs. mobile SDKs).

Since you want to track pageviews via JavaScript you'd use a web property.

Comment: So what should website URL be? Note that I want to ideally collect data from all of the websites that embed my module... Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter. The website Url setting is used in the preview feature and in-page analyses, it's not relevant for data collection. Put in there whatever you like.